# why numpy array has size of 112 byte and when I do flatten it, it has 96 byte of memory?

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

I have a numpy array and I flatten it by np.ravel() and I am confused when i tried to learn the size of the both array

> > > array =np.arange(15).reshape(3,5)
> > >
> > > sys.getsizeof(array)
> > >       112
> > >
> > > sys.getsizeof(array.ravel())
> > >       96
> > >
> > > array.size
> > >       15
> > >
> > > array.ravel().size
> > >       15

> > > array = np.arange(30).reshape(5,6)
> > >
> > > sys.getsizeof(array)
> > >       112
> > >
> > > sys.getsizeof(array.ravel())
> > >       96
> > >
> > > array.size
> > >       30

As seen above two different arrays have the same memory size but each has different amount of element. Why does it happen?

Comment: All the arrays you are testing are views, and don't own their own data buffer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) `ravel()` usually (see @user2357112 's comments below) returns an object that references the items of the input rather than making a new copy:

```
>>> a = np.arange(15)
>>> b = a.ravel()
>>> b
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14])
>>> a[0]=5
>>> b
array([ 5,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14])
```

`sys.getsizeof(array.ravel())` doesn't change no matter how big `array` is.

(2) Similarly, `reshape()` doesn't copy the items:

```
>>> b = a.reshape(3,5)
>>> b
array([[ 5,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
>>> a[0] = 7
>>> b
array([[ 7,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
```

Again, the memory usage stays constant when you increase the size of the input array (and adjust the shape accordingly).

(3) Yes, the other answers are right in that `sys.getsizeof()` may be missing some of the memory needed by third party objects. However, a simple test suggests that the main part of numpy arrays is accounted for:

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(np.arange(20))
256
>>> sys.getsizeof(np.arange(40))
416
>>> sys.getsizeof(np.arange(400))
3296
```

Comment: `ravel()` *usually* returns a view. In cases where the input strides make the creation of a flat view impossible, `ravel()` will make a copy. This is often forgotten.

Comment: Same with `reshape`.

Answer (score 0):

`sys.getsizeof` does not return the memory size of numpy array, as per documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof

> All built-in objects will return correct results, **but this does not have to hold true for third-party extensions as it is implementation specific**.

to find memory size of an numpy array use `nbytes` or compute it by multiplying the size with itemsize

`array.nbytes`

`array.size * array.itemsize`

as Joachim Wagner pointed out, there is slight overhead for each array that can be an issue if you have a lot of np arrays... the `sys.getsizeof(array)` might give you the size of this overhead but i am not sure

Comment: There is additional memory overhead for the python object and for telling numpy what type the items are, e.g. `int32` or `float64`.

Comment: does third-party extension mean the libraries(community made) of python?

Comment: yes, anything that does not come out of the box with python is a non built-in

Answer (score 0):

As Derte mentioned, `sys.getsizeof` doesn't say the size of the array. The `96` you got is holding information about the array (if it's 1-Dimensional) and the `112` if it's multi dimensional. Any additional element will increase the size with 8 bytes assuming you are using a `dtype=int64`.